# Can I query a modified object before saving its changes?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am authoring a domain model that I will later map to a database using EF Code First.  This is my first project using Entity Framework, and although I've read a book about it a while back, I can't remember all the details of how it works.

In one part of the domain model I have a one-to-many relationship.

```
public class Parent
{
    public IList<Child> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

After the user has modified an in-memory instance of `Parent`, and clicks a button, then it will be time to persist that instance to the database.  At that time, I must first run some domain-specific comparison logic between the instance as it exists in the database (before saving) and the unsaved modified version that's in memory.  So I need to query the database to retrieve an unmodified duplicate of the `Parent` instance and its `Children`.

Does EF Code First let me safely run such a query?  I just worry that when EF runs such a query it will see that each `Child` is already in memory and so reuse those instances, and overwrite their modifications, instead of instantiating duplicates.  In this situation, I in fact want the duplicates.

Comment: How do you get the in-memory instance? The main thing is, that if it is not tracked by the EntityChangeTracker then you need to "attach" it and mark its state to "modified" so that when you call the SaveChanges on the context it can know that it need to be updated. If you make a query it will be tracked but if you just "attach" it will be tracked as well and it takes less time.

Answer (score 0):

Code first lets you access the original and changed values of a tracked object like this:

```
Parent parent;
...
var curVal = context.Entry(parent).Property(p => p.Property).CurrentValue;
var origVal = context.Entry(parent).Property(p => p.Property).OriginalValue;
```

You should also be able to do this with individual values in the Children collection

Subsequent queries will supply a new set of entities with current database values, but if you want to check the cache the context holds, that's very straightforward as described here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2012/03/19/entity-framework-code-first-get-entities-from-local-cache-or-the-database.aspx

Comment: This code helps me visualize things, but let's return to my question: If I run a query after the instances were modified but before they are persisted, would that query (a) return an entirely new set of instances, (b) update the in-memory "original" values from the database without overwriting the "current" values, or (c) cause me to loose the modified values.